# Is it possible to import and add .xcframework file to a static xcode library project?

Tags: swift, objective-c, xcode, frameworks

I have set of .xcframework files, and currently I working on a static library

I need to integrate those .xcframework files into my static library, but it seems Build settings menu and build phase menu on a static library project is different and I can't add .xcframwork files like I used to do on a Xcode app project

Answer (score 1):

You add dependencies under **Build Phases** tab, in **Link Binary With Libraries** step:

[image]

Be advised that in this scenario you cannot embed any framework. It either has to be delivered alongside the library or adding the dependencies has to be part of the library integration instructions. I.e. the consumers of your library will need to add this `xcframework` dependency manually in their target.